# Perl shift operator simple question

Tags: perl, shift

What's the purpose of the following two lines of perl??

```
my $host = shift || 'localhost';
my $port = shift || 200;
```

That should return localhost and port 10. What is the shift keyword??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this piece of code is, is a way to provide default values for `$host` and `$port`. It will typically be at the start of a script or a subroutine, and take values from `@ARGV` and `@_` respectively.

> That should return localhost and port
>   10.

No, the `||` operator is a short circuiting `OR`, which means that if the LHS operand returns a true value, the RHS operand is ignored. Basically, it means this (and ONLY this): "choose the left hand side value if it is true, otherwise choose the right hand side value."

`shift ARRAY` will return the first value of `ARRAY`, or:

> If ARRAY is omitted, shifts the @_
>   array within the lexical scope of
>   subroutines and formats, and the @ARGV
>   array outside a subroutine and also
>   within the lexical scopes established
>   by the eval STRING , BEGIN {} , INIT
>   {} , CHECK {} , UNITCHECK {} and END
>   {} constructs.

Quoted from http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html

Also, of course, `shift` removes the value from the array that is shifted. Therefore you can have two `shift` in a row like this, for very convenient argument handling.

Comment: You're right, in fact I got wrong: it return port 200 as you have stated.

Answer (score 10):

The first line shifts from either `@_` or `@ARGV` (depending on where you are in the code), or in the absence of any contents in `@_`/`@ARGV`, assigns `localhost` to `$host`.

The second one should be self-explanatory now.

Have a look at [the shift documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) for details.

Comment: so it's like a stack pop, isn't it?

Comment: Pop comes off the top of the stack. Shift off the bottom

Answer (score 3):

If no argument is provided, [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) will shift @ARGV outside a subroutine and @_ inside a subroutine – that is the argument array passed to either the main program or the subroutine.

In your case, $host is assigned the first element of @ARGV (or @_, if the code is inside a sub) or 'localhost', if the element is false.

This is a very common Perl idiom.

Answer (score 2):

shift return the first element of an array and removes it from the array. Like pop, but from the other end.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `shift`, always put the array on it.  I've seen experience Perl programmers forget that outside a subroutine, `shift` works on `@ARGV`.  The more things a programmer has to remember at the same time, the more likely he is to make an error.